# Enum value not showing correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

In my Class A. I am using Enum Like this.

```
typedef enum {
    EditProfile,
    CreateProfile,
} AdressState;

@interface ManageAddress : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    AdressState state;
}
```

and assign  a value in .m file

```
-(IBAction)adress:(id)sender
{
    state = CreateProfile;
    MyAddress *my = [[MyAddress alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyAddress" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:my animated:YES];
}
```

On my `MyAddressController` I am accessing enum value

```
@interface MyAddress : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>
{
    AdressState state;
}
```

.m file

```
if (state == EditProfile )
{
    mobile.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"mobile"];
}
```

My state show always EditProfile but I am assign a value CreateProfile. Please help.

Comment: Can't help without seeing how you set the `state` instance variable.

Comment: I am not using  state anywhere

Comment: So you don't assign `state` so it's set to `0` (`EditProfile`) and you're asking why it always shows `EditProfile`?  Is that correct?

Comment: Please stop wasting our time with your non-questions.

Comment: Please follow standard coding conventions. Instance variables should start with an underscore, to avoid confusion between setters, getters, and instance variables. And you have two different instance variables in different classes with the same name; setting one doesn't affect the other.

Comment: The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the value from `ManageAddress`'s `state` member variable to that of `MyAddress`'s `state` member variable as they are both in different classes. Just update your `(IBAction)adress:(id)sender` mthod to the following:

```
-(IBAction)adress:(id)sender{
    state = CreateProfile;
    MyAddress *my =[[MyAddress alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyAddress" bundle:nil];
    my.state = state;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:my animated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create your `enum` globally like in AppDelegate or Singleton class and than assign current state from `ManageAddress` and get it on `MyAddress`

[image]

Assign here:

```
-(IBAction)adress:(id)sender {

AppDelegate *appDelegate  = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.state = CreateProfile;
MyAddress *my =[[MyAddress alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyAddress" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:my animated:YES];

}
```

Get here:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate  = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if (appDelegate.state == EditProfile ) {
    mobile.text =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"mobile"];
}
```

Comment: why some one mark down vote my answer? give me reason.

Comment: Because all you have done is move where the `enum` is declared. The code you show is the same as the OPs.  What is the point of your answer?

Comment: I asked to create enum globally and enum value can be assigned/accessed anywhere in the project. That's the thing he wanted to do in code.

Comment: But the code is the same as the OPs and all you have done is moved the `enum` declaration.  if there was a problem with the `enum` declaration then the OP would have mentioned a compiler error.  Your answer is wrong.

Comment: The difference it that he declared AdressState obj's locally in ManageAddress & MyAddress so he is unable to get values of enum becoz he is not passing the value. I just created it globally to access enum value.

Comment: Ah I see; the code *is* different.  However why move it into the App Delegate when you can simply make it a property and use `my.state = self.state;`?  I will remove my downvote, however as your answer is not at all that bad.